# FreeBSD CPU frequency scaling on AMD Sempron 2100

Tags: freebsd, power-management, cpu-frequency

I have FreeBSD 9.0-RC3 installed on an HP Thin Client that has a Mobile AMD Sempron(tm) Processor 2100+. I am trying to get cpufreq and powerd to manage the frequency of the processor, but I'm not having any luck. Here's some lines from dmesg:

```
FreeBSD 9.0-RC3 #0: Sun Dec  4 08:56:36 UTC 2011
    root@farrell.cse.buffalo.edu:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC amd64
CPU: Mobile AMD Sempron(tm) Processor 2100+ (997.52-MHz K8-class CPU)
  Origin = "AuthenticAMD"  Id = 0x60fc2  Family = f  Model = 6c  Stepping = 2
  Features=0x78bfbff<FPU,VME,DE,PSE,TSC,MSR,PAE,MCE,CX8,APIC,SEP,MTRR,PGE,MCA,CMOV,PAT,PSE36,CLFLUSH,MMX,FXSR,SSE,SSE2>
  Features2=0x2001<SSE3,CX16>
  AMD Features=0xea500800<SYSCALL,NX,MMX+,FFXSR,RDTSCP,LM,3DNow!+,3DNow!>
  AMD Features2=0x119<LAHF,ExtAPIC,CR8,Prefetch>

module_register: module cpu/ichss already exists!
Module cpu/ichss failed to register: 17
module_register: module cpu/est already exists!
Module cpu/est failed to register: 17
module_register: module cpu/hwpstate already exists!
Module cpu/hwpstate failed to register: 17
module_register: module cpu/p4tcc already exists!
Module cpu/p4tcc failed to register: 17
module_register: module cpu/powernow already exists!
Module cpu/powernow failed to register: 17

powerd: lookup freq: No such file or directory
```

Also, `sysctl dev | grep freq` returns no hits.

Any suggestions on how to get CPU frequency management working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though there isn't any.

[The FreeBSD forums folks have weighed in](https://forums.freebsd.org/showthread.php?p=157595), and there's no support for CPU frequency management on this chip.  [AMD's spec sheet](http://www.amd.com/us/Documents/9W_Sempron_FINAL_5.23.pdf) makes no mention of PowerNow, either.

This isn't surprising - small-form-factor boxes (like the T5730w; is that what you have?) are often built to run cool and low-power anyway.  The Sempron 2100+ is 9W and built to be fanless, which fits that model.

If you're actually having heat issues, you might be able to replace a chassis fan or otherwise improve air flow, but I think the CPU's not going to cooperate.